# Format Twitter API Date uses moment.js on node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter

I'm currently trying to format the Twitter API Date however I'm unsure how to access it and resend it within the express router as data to then use in a Jade file.

```js
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function (error, tweets, response) {
    Promise.all([
      getArticles(),
      getInstas()
    ])
      .then(data => res.render('pages/news-centre/home', {
        articles: data[0].slice(0, 4),
        tweets: tweets,
        instagram: data[1].data
      }))
    .catch(next)
  })
})
```

I am using the [Twitter API Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) from npm. I'm getting my instagram and article json data from promises in a `utilitys.js` file.

I can access the twitter date using jade via `#{tweets[i].created_at}` however I'd like to format them using moment.js before I do.

Would be great if someone could point me in the correct direction I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without knowing the format of what's in `tweets`, but you should probably do this:

```
  .then(data => res.render('pages/news-centre/home', {
    articles: data[0].slice(0, 4),
    tweets: tweets.map(tweet => ({
        text: tweet.text,
        created_at: moment(tweet.created_at, INPUT_FORMAT).format(OUTPUT_FORMAT),
        // etc, grab the rest of the fields you need
    })),
    instagram: data[1].data
  }))
```

You could technically also modify the original `tweet` object to contain a `created_at_formatted` property (or something), then return `tweet`, but that's technically a bit of an anti-pattern. Might be a quick solution if you don't feel like picking out *every single* property you need from the `tweet` object.

Comment: 'tweets` returns the json data of the API call for a twitter user, example can be found here - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline. Wont this solution affect any of the other data? Since I am also using `#{tweets[i].text}`. Apologises if not making much sense - a little new to API's and express routing!

Comment: Map doesn't change the original items (unless you explicitly change them in the callback, which is typically a bad idea), but you will have to decide what you want to take with. Essentially, grab what you need to render your home page. Updated answer to (hopefully) give a better example.